# Extracting and printing the first 3 octets of a MAC using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, mac-address

```
if($ping)
    {
        ( $mac | ? { $_ -match $ip } ) -match "([0-9A-F]{2}([:-][0-9A-F]{2}){5})" | out-null;
        if ( $matches ) {
            Select-String -Pattern '[0-9A-F]{2}-[0-9A-F]{2}-[0-9A-F]{2}' -Path $matches[0] |
            ForEach-Object {$_.Matches[0].Value}
        } else {
            "Not Found"
        }
    }
```

Is what I am currently using. Not sure if I am doing this right in PowerShell.

I am trying to Extract the first 3 XX:XX:XX of a MAC so that I can use it for a compare. I'm just not sure how pull after the match.

Comment: This code is a mess.. which part is not working? What's happening? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Remove` to crop the first 8 characters:

```
$mac ='00:0a:95:9d:68:16' 

$mac.Remove(8, ($mac.Length -8))
```

Output:

```
00:0a:95
```

You can also do it using a regex:

```
[regex]::Match($mac, '^(.{8})').Groups[1].Value
```